# Hard code a link in package.json

Tags: npm

I am either using wrong search keywords or this feature does not exist.

NPM offers a [`link` feature](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) for symlink-ing packages.

The way it works is that you call `npm link` in the working directory of the package that you want to link, and `npm link [package-name]` in the working directory of the script in which you want to use the former package.

I have a repository `foo`, which has a subfolder `example`. `example` directory is a standalone private package that uses `foo` package. I use it to demonstrate the use of the `foo` package.

I can make `example` use the `foo` package by doing:

```sh
cd /foo
npm link
cd /foo/example 
npm link foo
```

Is there a way to hard code this link in the `/foo/example/package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

No.

This is 30 chars to appease SO